# Android Room - SerializedName Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it

Tags: android, json, database, kotlin, android-room

How can I make nested jsons into android room?
Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.

private final com.kbb.webviewolacakmi.model.content icerik = null;

private final com.kbb.webviewolacakmi.model.title baslik = null;

```
@Entity
data class Icerik(
    @ColumnInfo(name="title")
    @SerializedName("title")
    val baslik:title?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="content")
    @SerializedName("content")
    val icerik:content?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="date")
    @SerializedName("date")
    val tarih:String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="jetpack_featured_media_url")
    @SerializedName("jetpack_featured_media_url")
    val gorsel:String?,) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var uuid:Int=0

}
data class content(
    @ColumnInfo(name="rendered")
    @SerializedName("rendered")
    val content: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="protected")
    @SerializedName("protected")
    val bool: Boolean?,
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var uuid:Int=0
}
data class title(
    @ColumnInfo(name="rendered")
    @SerializedName("rendered")
    val ytitle:String?
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var uuid:Int=0
}
```

- 

```
interface IcerikDAO {
    @Insert
    suspend fun instertAll(vararg icerik:Icerik):List<Long>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM icerik")
    suspend fun getAllIcerik():List<Icerik>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM icerik WHERE uuid=:icerikId")
    suspend fun getIcerik(icerikId:Int):Icerik
    @Query("DELETE FROM icerik")
    suspend fun deleteAllBesin()
}
```

- 

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Icerik::class), version = 1)
abstract class IcerikDatabase:RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun icerikDao(): IcerikDAO

    companion object {
        @Volatile private var instance:IcerikDatabase? = null
        private val lock=Any()
        operator fun invoke(context: Context)= instance?: synchronized(lock){
            instance?: databaseOlustur(context).also {
                instance=it
            }
        }


        private fun databaseOlustur(context: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(
            context.applicationContext, IcerikDatabase::class.java,
            "icerikdatabase"
        ).build()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can consider adding a type converter for it.

Comment: I'm learning new can you help me?

Comment: What the error says is that `Room` doesn't know how to save `content` and `title` because it's not a simple string or number that SQL would recognise. Basically what you are trying to do is to have them as `@ForeinKey`.  Also you do not have `content` and `title` annotated with `@Entity`.

Comment: I'm getting the values with json but I don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could code the TypeConverters:-

```
class RoomTypeConverters {

    /* Note using dependency upon com.google.code.gson */

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTitleToJSONString(title: title?): String? {
        return Gson().toJson(title)
    }
    @TypeConverter
    fun toTitleFromJSONString(jsonString: String?): title? {
        return Gson().fromJson(jsonString,title::class.java)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromIcerikToJSONString(content: content?): String? {
        return Gson().toJson(content)
    }
    @TypeConverter
    fun toIcrerikFromJSONString(jsonString: String?): content? {
        return Gson().fromJson(jsonString, content::class.java)
    }
}
```

You then have to include the `@TypeConverters` annotation (not plural as opposed to singular). TypeConverters have scope so for the highest scope then it can be coded within the `@Database` annotated class e.g. :-

```
@TypeConverters(value = [RoomTypeConverters::class]) //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Icerik::class), version = 1)
abstract class IcerikDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun icerikDao(): IcerikDAO
    ....
```

As an example usage, consider the following (adapted to run on the main thread for convenience and brevity):-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var icerikDatabase: IcerikDatabase
    lateinit var icerikDAO: IcerikDAO
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        icerikDatabase = IcerikDatabase.invoke(this)
        icerikDAO = icerikDatabase.icerikDao()

        val i1 = Icerik(baslik = title("b1"), icerik = content("b1content",true),tarih = "Test", gorsel = "test")
        val i2 = Icerik(baslik = title("b2"), icerik = content("b2content",true),tarih = "Test", gorsel = "test")
        val i3 = Icerik(baslik = title(null), icerik = content(null,null), tarih = null, gorsel =  null)
        val i4 = Icerik(baslik = null, icerik = null, tarih = null, gorsel =  null)

        icerikDAO.instertAll(i1,i2,i3,i4)
        for (i in icerikDAO.getAllIcerik()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","ID=${i.uuid}")
        }
    }
}
```

The result in the log:-

```
2022-10-22 14:56:27.281 D/DBINFO: ID=1
2022-10-22 14:56:27.281 D/DBINFO: ID=2
2022-10-22 14:56:27.281 D/DBINFO: ID=3
2022-10-22 14:56:27.281 D/DBINFO: ID=4
```

i.e. the four inserts have obviously worked and also the extract

The resultant database:-

[image]

---

**However**, the result is a waste of space and introduces unneeded complexities and thus inherent inefficiencies, you might as well just embed the converted classes and:

- each field would be a column of the table
- the JSON bloat (field descriptors and separators) would not need to be stored

  - e.g. instead of 1 byte, if embedded, for the **bool** aka **protected** data the JSON version takes up 18 bytes of storage and so on.
- there would be no need for type converters.
- Furthermore the ability to filter extracts would be simpler, for example you could simply have a filter on `WHERE protected` as opposed to something like `WHERE instr(content,"protected":true)`

As such you may wish to consider this alternative approach (embedded rather than converted class as JSON string in a single column):-

So for example :-

```
@Entity
data class IcerikAlt(
    /* More efficient primary key as the unnecessary and inefficient AUTOINCREMENT is not used */
    /* also as Long instead of Int less likely to overflow */
    /**/
    @PrimaryKey
    val uuid: Long?=null,
    @Embedded
    val baslik: title?,
    @Embedded
    val icerik: content?,
    val tarih: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="jetpack_featured_media_url")
    @SerializedName("jetpack_featured_media_url")
    val gorsel: String?
)
data class content(
    @ColumnInfo(name="content_rendered") /* CHANGED to differentiate like named columns */
    @SerializedName("content_rendered") /* CHANGED to differentiate like named columns */
    val content: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="protected")
    @SerializedName("protected")
    val bool: Boolean?,
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "content_uuid") /* CHANGED to differentiate like named columns */
    var uuid:Int=0
}
data class title(
    @ColumnInfo(name="title_rendered") /* CHANGED to differentiate like named columns */
    @SerializedName("title_rendered") /* CHANGED to differentiate like named columns */
    val ytitle:String?
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title_uuid") /* ADDED to differentiate uuid columns */
    var uuid:Int=0
}
```

Then using (i.e. old(converted classes) and suggested(embedded)):-

```
    val i1 = Icerik(baslik = title("b1"), icerik = content("b1content",true),tarih = "Test", gorsel = "test")
    val i2 = Icerik(baslik = title("b2"), icerik = content("b2content",true),tarih = "Test", gorsel = "test")
    val i3 = Icerik(baslik = title(null), icerik = content(null,null), tarih = null, gorsel =  null)
    val i4 = Icerik(baslik = null, icerik = null, tarih = null, gorsel =  null)

    val ia1 = IcerikAlt(baslik = title("b1"), icerik = content("b1content",true),tarih = "Test", gorsel = "test")
    val ia2 = IcerikAlt(baslik = title("b2"), icerik = content("b2content",true),tarih = "Test", gorsel = "test")
    val ia3 = IcerikAlt(baslik = title(null), icerik = content(null,null), tarih = null, gorsel =  null)
    val ia4 = IcerikAlt(baslik = null, icerik = null, tarih = null, gorsel =  null)


    icerikDAO.instertAll(i1,i2,i3,i4)
    for (i in icerikDAO.getAllIcerik()) {
        Log.d("DBINFO","ID=${i.uuid}")
    }

    icerikDAO.insertAll(ia1,ia2,ia3,ia4)
    for (i in icerikDAO.getAllIcerikAlt()) {
        Log.d("DBINFO","ID=${i.uuid}")
    }
```

The result in the Log:-

```
2022-10-22 15:44:27.873 D/DBINFO: ID=1
2022-10-22 15:44:27.874 D/DBINFO: ID=2
2022-10-22 15:44:27.874 D/DBINFO: ID=3
2022-10-22 15:44:27.874 D/DBINFO: ID=4


2022-10-22 15:44:27.881 D/DBINFO: ID=1
2022-10-22 15:44:27.881 D/DBINFO: ID=2
2022-10-22 15:44:27.881 D/DBINFO: ID=3
2022-10-22 15:44:27.881 D/DBINFO: ID=4
```

- i.e. same (effectively) four rows added

The Alternative table however:-

[image]

- although more columns less data and the data is easier to see and easier to filter and more compact storage wise.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am getting this error error: Cannot find getter for field.
    private final com.kbb.webviewolacakmi.model.content icerik = null;

Comment: @KerimBerkay if it's private the you need a getter (function to return the value e.g.  something like fun getIcerik():  content? = this.icerik). Private is saying you cannot set or get the values, you have to ask for them through a method, if I allow it, for you to get the value(s). Easiest fix, remove the private. Perhaps see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/visibility-modifiers.html#class-members

Comment: If possible, can you write that code as well?